# alter table script in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

If i have a table_abc. Now i alter and add few columns in this like

```
alter table_Abc add ( congif_id number, sso number);
```

Now second time i add few columns along with congif_id and sso like :

```
alter table_Abc add ( congif_id number, sso number,name varchar2(100));
```

but this is throwing error `column already exists.`

Shouldnt the alter script still run even if the names are same and add the new ones ?

Comment: How can you add the same column twice?

Comment: NO, you added once why adding it again just remove the columns that has been created once

Comment: its a script which we re-ran.

Comment: You're probably expecting "create or replace" type of behavior as works with some other Oracle DDL. But that's not standard and doesn't work for `alter table`.

Answer (score 1):

No, that error is to be expected.  If necessary you can make your DDL script re-runnable using dynamic SQL, for example:

```
begin
   execute immediate
   'alter table table_Abc add ( congif_id number)';
exception
   when others then 
      if sqlcode = -1430 then
         null;
      end if;
end;

begin
   execute immediate
   'alter table table_Abc add ( sso number)';
exception
   when others then 
      if sqlcode = -1430 then
         null;
      end if;
end;
...
```

Or if you do this sort of thing a lot:

```
declare
   procedure run_ddl
      ( p_sql varchar2
      , p_ignored_exception integer
      )
   is
   begin
      execute immediate p_sql;
   exception
      when others then 
         if sqlcode = p_ignored_exception then
            null;
         end if;
   end;
begin
   run_ddl ('alter table table_Abc add ( congif_id number)', -1430);
   run_ddl ('alter table table_Abc add ( sso number)', -1430);
end;
```